# Value <unavailable> in IAR

Tags: c, iar

I am using IAR (Version: 6.60.1.5104) to run my C project.

I am seeing a strange behavior.

While debugging I am getting the value of a variable  defined locally as `zero`

eg.

```
int a = 0
```

But for a variable assigned a non-zero value is `<available>`.

I have mentioned a code snippet below:

```
int someFun():
{
    int32_t a = 0; //IAR says it <unavailable>
    int32_t b = 1;
    printf("%d%d", a,b);
}
```

This is consistently happening. Please help

Answer (score 3):

This probably just means that the variable has been optimized away, i.e. when the program runs there is no variable. Since the variable's value is never changed, an optimizing compiler is free to remove it and just make the `printf()` call use the values directly.

Disassemble the program to see how the call is generated.

Investigate how to disable compiler optimizations for your particular compiler (read the docs).

Comment: This is the likely cause. IAR (ARM) will aggressively re-use CPU registers on optimization levels 'Low' and above. If my memory serves me correctly 'Low' is enabled even on debug builds by default, while lowest possible level is 'None'.

Comment: Since IAR (8051 in my case) will aggressively optimize away lines, if you want to break in that area, you can't since the lines are gone. You can put in an asm("nop"); line and break on that. The optimizer won't touch that line. Is there a similar trick to get the optimizer to never whisk away a variable?

Comment: Declare the variable as 'volatile' to work around this. I can't believe I didn't think of that before.